# ¿Cómo puedo hallar el valor máximo de este SortedMap?

Tags: java

pues esa es la pregunta estoy intentando hallar el valor máximo que hace corresponder a cada asignatura que aparece en el expediente del alumno con la calificación máxima obtenida en ella , en este SortedMap.
A la hora de hacerme el Integer aux = map.get(n.getAsignaturas()) me da fallo puesto que el "valor" (calificacion) no es un integer, es una clase Enum como podría arreglar eso? 
Saludos , y dejo aqui el codigo , a ver si pueden dar ideas!(getNotas es una coleccion, y Asignatura/Calificacion dos clases)

```
public SortedMap<Asignatura, Calificacion> getCalificacionPorAsignatura() {
    SortedMap<Asignatura, Calificacion> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for(Nota n:getExpediente().getNotas()){
        if(getAsignaturas().contains(n.getAsignatura())){
            if(map.containsKey(n.getAsignatura())){
                Integer aux = map.get(n.getAsignatura());

            }else{
                map.put(n.getAsignatura(),n.getCalificacion());
        }
    }
}
    return map;
}
```

Comment: puedes agregar la declaración del enum que retorna GetAsignatura?

Comment: Tu mapa es declarado como `SortedMap<Asignatura, Calificacion>`. Es decir, las llaves son de tipo `Asignatura` y los valores de tipo `Calificacion`. Por ende, cuando ejecutas `map.get(n.getAsignatura());` el valor devuelto será un objeto de tipo `Calificacion`, no un `Integer`.  Lo que quieres es obtener el valor de la calificación almacenado en `Calificacion`, por lo que luego que has obtenido la `Calificacion` deberias acceder al campo de tipo `Integer` o algo similar.

Comment: Claro , ese es el problema que tengo que no se como acceder a ese campo de tipo Integer

Comment: No entiendo el problema. Por favor coloca el código de `Calificacion` para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es un Enum, puedes obtenerlo así:

```
Integer aux = map.get(n.getAsignatura()).ordinal();
```

acerca del método **[ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29)** (inglés)

Comment: Muchas gracias , la verdad que me ha servido @Elenasys , lo he podido completar ! Pero habría otra forma de convertir ese Enum a Integer ? Simplemente por curiosidad.

Comment: Presiento que eso hará que el código compile pero no sé si sea una solución. Es más, la pregunta de por sí suena un poco indescifrable.